# Apollonios equation holds iff the norm is induced by a scalar product

Tags: normed-spaces, scalar-fields

Let $(E, \vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert )$ be a normed space. The norm is induced by  a scalar product iff in  $(E, \vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert )$ the Apollonios equation holds.

The Apollonios equation:
$\frac{1}{2} \vert \vert x-y \vert \vert ^2 + 2\cdot \vert \vert z -\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\vert \vert ^2 = \vert \vert z-x \vert \vert ^2+\vert \vert z-y \vert \vert ^2$

So I have to prove: 
$\vert \vert x\vert \vert =\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} \vert \vert x-y \vert \vert ^2 + 2\cdot \vert \vert z -\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\vert \vert ^2 = \vert \vert z-x \vert \vert ^2+\vert \vert z-y \vert \vert ^2$.

The direction   $\Rightarrow$ was easy. How do I prove $\Leftarrow$? My idea was to show that the properties of the norm and the scalar product are the same. But it seems to be too complicated. Is there any easy way to prove it?

Comment: Put $z=0$ to get parallelogram identity. Then use polarization identity to define the inner product. This is quite standard.

Comment: Then I have $\langle x,y \rangle = - \frac{1}{2} (\vert \vert x \vert \vert^2 + \vert \vert y \vert \vert^2)$. Should I prove that this is indeed the inner product?

Comment: How did you get this equation? This is certainly not an inner product.

Comment: If $z=0$, then we have $\vert \vert x+y \vert \vert^2+\vert \vert x-y \vert \vert^2 = 2( \vert \vert x \vert \vert^2 + \vert \vert y \vert \vert^2)$

Comment: Please go to the following link for polarization identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: polaritation identity: $\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{4} (\vert \vert x+y\vert \vert^2 - \vert \vert x-y\vert \vert^2)$

Comment: My bad. There is a minus in the polarisation identity

Comment: Then it is $\langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(\vert \vert x \vert \vert^2 + \vert \vert y \vert \vert^2 - \vert \vert x-y \vert \vert^2)$

Answer (score 1):

If someone gives you a normed space, it is quite a challenge to come up with a definition of the inner product. Sure, $\langle x, x \rangle$ is easy for every $x$, but what about $\langle x, y \rangle$? If you can come up with the right definition of $\langle x, y \rangle$ in terms of the norm, then you are half way there. Actually this is the interesting, creative half.

But then you still need to verify that the function $\langle , \rangle$ from $E \times E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has indeed the three or so properties that make it an inner product. This is the boring, routine verification half, but that is where you need Apollonios.

Comment: Can I use the polarization identity?

Comment: It's not much of a challenge: if a normed space is Euclidean, the inner product has to be related to the norm by $\langle v, w \rangle = (\|v + w\|^2 - \|v\|^2 - \|w\|^2)/2$ (which is just like the formula you have in $\Bbb{R}$: $xy = ((x+y)^2 -x^2-y^2)/2$).

Comment: ... and yes, that little law and some other more or less similar ones masquerade under the posh name of the *polarization identity*.